# Firestore Permission Denied inspite of rules matching document set path

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am out of ideas. Hope a fresh eye can help.

I have the following security rules:

```
function isUser (request, userKey) {
  return request.auth.uid == userKey;
}

function isAuthorized(request){
    return request.auth.uid != null;
}

function isAdmin (request) {
  return root.child('users').child(request.auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true;
}

service cloud.firestore{
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{uid} {
          allow create: if isAuthorized(request) || isAdmin(request);
          allow update: if isUser(request, uid) || isAdmin(request);
        }

        match /userReadable/{objectType}/{uid} {
          allow read: if isUser(request, uid) || isAdmin(request);
          allow write: if isAdmin(request);
        }

        match /userWriteable/{objectType}/{uid} {
          allow read: if isAdmin(request);
          allow write: if isUser(request, uid) || isAdmin(request);
        }

        match /userOwned/{objectType}/{uid} {
          allow read: if isUser(request, uid) || isAdmin(request);
          allow write: if isUser(request, uid) || isAdmin(request);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am setting the document in the following code:

```
 FirebaseFirestore db = getDB();
        PulseFirebaseModel pulse = new PulseFirebaseModel((PulseModel) object);
        try {
            final DocumentReference doc = db.collection(COLLECTION_USER_WRITABLE)
                    .document(OBJECT_PULSE_SAMPLE)
                    .collection(FirebaseApp.getInstance().getUid())
                    .document();

            doc.set(pulse, SetOptions.merge())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "Saved sample: " + doc.getId() +"\t"+doc.getPath());
                                onSuccess();
                            }else{
                                onFailure("Could not save Ppg\t"
                                        + task.getException().getMessage()
                                        + "\ndoc Path:" + doc.getPath()
                                        + "\ndoc id: " + doc.getId()
                                        + "\n" + task.getResult());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (FirebaseApiNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

I am getting the following Permission denied message:

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>
> doc Path:userWriteable/pulseSample/xxxxx/Bba6pdgfMY98NmsAg1Hl
>
> doc id: Bba6pdgfMY98NmsAg1Hl

this is my UID as registered by FirebaseApp :
Uid: xxxxx

the `/users/{uid}` match works perfectly. And I haven't implemented the other 2 matches.
I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890785/firestore-transactions-giving-permission-denied) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439322/access-parent-documents-field-in-firestore-rules) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439322/access-parent-documents-field-in-firestore-rules)
I am signed in and request is sent with the correct request.auth.uid

I simply can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting to see your use of `FirebaseApp.getInstance().getUid()`. It seems to return the same UID as `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`, but it's not in the [documentation for FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) .

Comment: @BobSnyder - At the end of the day, there is the default underlying FirebaseApp which is used in FirebaseAuth. If you look at the getInstance here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are writing to an auto-generated document ID with [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()), your rules need to include a wildcard for the document ID at the end of the path:

```
match /userWriteable/{objectType}/{uid}/{docId} { // <== added /{docId}
  allow read: if isAdmin(request);
  allow write: if isUser(request, uid) || isAdmin(request);
}
```